# MGCV error - not finding variable

Tags: r, mgcv

In a much larger dataset, I am getting an error saying the variable is not available for a mgcv model fit. I've been able to reproduce with a toy example, below. For context, the variable causing the issue is a data indicator flag (for genuinely undefined / non-existant data measurements, as per [Handling NAs in a regression ?? Data Flags?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358443/handling-nas-in-a-regression-data-flags?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

I am getting an error saying a variable is not available 'Error in eval(parse(text = terms[i]), enclos = p.env, envir = mgcvns): object 'obs_flag' not found'

As you can see, the error is only occurring when there is an interaction between the flag and spline variable.

```
library(mgcv)
test = data.frame('num_var' = rep(c(0,5,7,11,30,100,0), 3), 
'obs_flag' = rep(factor(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), 3), 
'target' = rep(factor(c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes')), 3))

my_formula_working <- target ~ obs_flag:num_var
my_formula_not_working <- target ~ obs_flag:s(num_var)
    
fit1 = gam( my_formula_working1, family=binomial(link = logit), data = test ,  na.action = na.fail, method = 'REML')
fit2 = gam( my_formula_not_working, family=binomial(link = logit), data = test ,  na.action = na.fail, method = 'REML')
```

Comment: Hi @Meep, is there a _statistical_ question here? If not, it might be better to ask this on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Try `my_formula_not_working <- target ~ s(num_var, by = obs_flag)`. It still errors but it's a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different issues here:

1. You can't have a meaningful interaction term because `num_var` is always 0 when `obs_flag` is `FALSE`. Look at the output of `fit1`.
2. The correct syntax in the second model would be `s(num_var, by = obs_flag)`.
3. If you correct the formula in the second model you'll get the error `A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom`. This is because `num_var` doesn't have enough distinct values for the default number of splines. I assume this is not an issue in your full data set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. #1 relates to the data indicator flag question I cited - where it is impossible to provide a real valuable for an explanatory var (e.g. 'time since last treatment' when there is no previous treatment). . #2 fixed my issue, thanks!